# STM32: HAL_UART_Transmit_IT function doesnt print the value

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, uart, cubemx

at the beginning, I'm relatively new to the world of microcontroller programming

I have a problem with HAL_UART_Transmit_IT called in another callback function (HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback).
I want to write a simple program that will read the information from UART and then write it out in an unchanged form (echo). Function in "poll mode" - HAL_UART_Transmit() - works good but I want to do all functionality on interrupts.

```
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f303xe.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <string.h>

void SystemClockConfig(void);
void UART2_Init(void);
void Error_handler (void);
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

char *myUserData = "*** Communication Starts ***\n\r";
uint8_t data_buffer[100];
uint32_t count = 0;
uint8_t rcvd_data;

int main (void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClockConfig();
    UART2_Init();

    if(HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)myUserData, strlen(myUserData), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &rcvd_data,1); // receive message from UART
    while(1)
    {
        // it works ok
        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)myUserData, strlen(myUserData));
        HAL_Delay(5000);
    }

    return 0;
}

void UART2_Init(void)
{
    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200 ;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(rcvd_data == '\r')
    {
        data_buffer[count++]='\r';
        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(huart, data_buffer, count); // here is a problem. HAL_UART_TRANSMIT() works ok
            // clear array for next incoming message.
            // whether it is the right place for such an operation?
            for (int i=0; i<sizeof(data_buffer);++i)
            {
                data_buffer[i] = 0;
            }

    } else {
    data_buffer[count++] = rcvd_data;
    }
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &rcvd_data,1); // receive next byte

}

void SystemClockConfig(void)
{
// Do Nothing
}

void Error_handler (void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

What's more, I would like to ask you if cleaning the array in callback function is a good solution or should it be solved differently?

Comment: I don't have the docs handy, but IIRC `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` doesn't make a copy of the buffer, so you need to wait for the transmit callback before modifying `data_buffer` again. In general you should do as little as possible in your interrupt routines (rx/tx callbacks), probably just setting a flag and checking that in your main loop. Be aware that not all (in fact most) functions aren't safe to call from an interrupt context (don't recall if that's the case for the UART IT functions though)

Comment: Hey, thanks. It helped. I tried to give a delay (calmly, just for debugging) but it did not help. After removing the `data_buffer` cleaning function, it started to work.

Comment: IIRC the delay function depends on a timer interrupt with lower priority, another reason to do less in an interrupt context :)